# What book is abbreviated as "Dor. Har."?

Tags: history, product-recommendation

There is a source text in the book "Jewish Time Line Encyclopedia" that is abbreviated at "Dor.Har." (https://books.google.co.il/books?id=1SD_AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=iw&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=dor.har.&f=false)

What book is this?

Comment: Does this question have to do with Judaism? If so, can you [edit] it to indicate how? Please see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Whenever you see an abbreviation in a footnote in a book that's at all scholarly, I recommend that you look in the back of the book for a bibliography. Most likely, you'll find an expansion of the abbreviation, often as part of a complete bibliographic note. In this case, the expansion is found p. 309, in the search results your link brings up.

Comment: @IsaacMoses haha I tried but wasn't able to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dorot Harishonim דורות הראשונים

See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_Isaac_Halevy_Rabinowitz) link in English about the author and the book